# Elgato game capture HD on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: video, games, youtube, video-capture-card

I wish to begin recording videos using the elgato game capture HD on a PS4. However, i have heard various problems with its use in Linux, so i have a few questions. Firstly, do i have to use the elgato software to start a recording on the ps4? (which i am sure will not work with ubuntu)  And,if this is not the case, will i be able to access these files once i connect it to my laptop? Like an external storage device? And,lastly, (if i can make it this far.) Will the files on the device be able to be moved over to my hard drive to edit them with Avidemux, Pitivi, Openshot, etc? Thanks in advance! and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

An experimental Linux driver for the Elgato Game Capture HD has been developed since you asked your question. For more information:

- [Driver webpage on GitHub](https://github.com/tolga9009/elgato-gchd)
- [Detailed, text-based tutorial for Ubuntu](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/streaming-on-linux-using-elgato-game-capture-hd-and-obs-studio.294/)
- [A video tutorial using Arch Linux may be found on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpm6TJu6HkE)